# Removing duplicates in linked list in C doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I'm trying to remove duplicates from the linked list and this code doesn't work. I would input the list of words, and it will print the same list before and after "removing". Some help please

```
typedef struct node {
    char data[50];
    struct node *next;
} *list;

void removeDuplicate(list words){
    list o = NULL, t = NULL, d = NULL;
    o = words;

    while(o != NULL && o->next != NULL){
        t = o;
        while(t->next != NULL){
            if(o->data == t->next->data){
                d = t->next;
                t->next = d->next->next;
                free(d);
            }
            else{
                t = t->next;
            }
        }
        o = o->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  Ideally, you'd provide an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))  However, in the code you show, you are comparing strings by comparing the pointers.  Each different structure has its string stored at a different address, so no two strings are the same.  You need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings in C.

Comment: this is your first mistake `if(o->data == t->next->data)` no need to go further

Comment: Please learn to think like a programmer. "Doesn't work" tells us nothing about what actually happens. And also you will only learn to resolve issues like this when you learn to better analyze what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `if(o->data == t->next->data)` as they are pointers to the starting location of the char array and will always be different. Try using `strcmp()`.